# Sonarqube error Either 'projectUuid' or 'projectKey' must be provided

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sonarqube

Hi I want set new quality profile. But I have this error :

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
        "msg": "Either 'projectUuid' or 'projectKey' must be provided"
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know why I have this error. Parameters `'projectKey'` is defined in my body.

URL : `http://sonarURL/api/qualityprofiles/add_project`

Body :

```
{
 "projectKey": "project_1",
 "qualityProfile": "Sonar way",
 "language": "java"
}
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the "problem". It's just that it's query params .........

Answer (score 0):

Use `project` instead of `projectKey`:

```
{
 "project": "project_1",
 "qualityProfile": "Sonar way",
 "language": "java"
}
```

Comment: What is your sonarqube version? Check documentation on your server: `http://sonarURL:9000/web_api/api/qualityprofiles/add_project`

Comment: 7.0. I see documentation it is written "project". What is strange is that if I make a query CURL it works